# Why is Genie routes.jl read only?

Tags: julia, genie.jl

I'm creating an MVC app, following [the tutorial](https://genieframework.github.io/Genie.jl/dev/tutorials/4-1--Developing_MVC_Web_Apps.html). I noticed that the `routes.jl` file is a read-only file. Why is that so? Shouldn't it be writable, because we need to change it by adding more routes?

The same question applies to files like `connection.yml` etc. Why are they read only?

Comment: Hi, yes `connection.yml` is read-only by default. I am not exactly sure why Adrian choose that design. I suggest you ask him directly on Genie Discord: https://discord.gg/9zyZbD6J7H

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reply I received from the community is that it is not meant to be read only. It becoming read only, is a bug which was supposed to have been fixed earlier.